# Similar to window.angular in angular2

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular

I am testing an application in browser and I need to check if the website is using `jquery` or `angularJs` or `angular`

For `jQuery` I can check for `$` function and for `angularJs` I can check for `window.angular` function. But is there anything similar for `angular 2/4/5` to check if its a `angular` application in browser?

Answer (score 0):

You could check for `ng`, which is a globally defined object to execute specific actions. E.g. you can enable debug tools which can then be accessed using the global `ng` object, but it's also available when the debug tools are disabled.

Comment: in the chrome browser the `ng` object in window scope is not available. remember I am not using angular inbuild testing. its external framework testing the website

Comment: Can we assume you know anything about the Angular app, such as a module name or is this more of black box test ? @AniruddhaDas

Comment: kind of black box testing where i dont know what developer used. i want to apply framework once I know this is `angular` or `angularJs` application

Comment: https://angular2.realworld.io/#/ here it is available in Chrome, as well as in the Angular app that I am currently working on when I do a production build. Which application are you referencing though that is not exposing the ng object?

Answer (score 0):

For angular 2 or higher you can use `window.getAllAngularTestabilities` to see if angular is available here.

```
if (window.angular && !(window.angular.version && window.angular.version.major > 1)) {
    definitelyNg1 = true;
} else if (window.getAllAngularTestabilities) {
    definitelyNg2OrNewer = true;
}

// See if our version of angular is ready
if (definitelyNg1) {
    if (window.angular && window.angular.resumeBootstrap) {
        // this is angularJs and do what ever you want
    }
} else if (definitelyNg2OrNewer) { //angular has no resumeBootstrap()
    if (true) {
        // process for angular 2 or higher
    }
}
```